# Error message from database execution: Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-administration

**Environment & Details**

- Environment – SQL Server 2014.
- All DB’s are participating in
  availability group.
- To connect to Read only node of Server, we
  created the linked server on both node.
- Internally,we have provided the Server DNS name and “ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly” as part of linked connection string. The linked server always read the data from secondary/read node.
- Linked server is using [ReadOnly] SQL user. This user has data reader permission on the selected database.
- Above Linked server – worked fine. And we are using the linked server in SQL jobs, which runs under the “sa” context.

**Problem**

- I am developing ADF pipeline. For the same, created the SQL user – “adfuser” on SQL server. This user has data reader, data writer permissions on required database.
- Now, I am trying following query under the ‘adfuser’ context.

  SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM [ReadOnly].DB.dbo.TableA.

**It is throwing an error –** 
*Database operation failed on server 'Server name' with SQL Error Number '7416'. Error message from database execution: Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.*

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Add “User ID=Username” into the provider string on your linked server when it's created.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N’LinkServerName’, @provider=N’SQLNCLI’,@srvproduct = ‘MS SQL Server’, @provstr=N’SERVER=serverName\InstanceName;User ID=myUser‘
```

you can read more here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/03/10/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists/